# Updating Labels in Tkinter with for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm trying to print items in a list dynamically on 10 tkinter `Label`s using a for loop. Currently I have the following code:

```
labe11 = StringVar()
list2_placer = 0
list1_placer = 1
mover = 227
for items in range(10):
    item_values = str(list1[list1_placer] + " " +list2[list2_placer])
    Label(canvas1, width="100", height="2",textvariable=labe11).place(x=200,y=mover)
    labe11.set(item_values)
    list1_placer = list1_placer +1
    list2_placer = list2_placer +1
    mover = mover +50
```

Where `list1` and `list2` are lists containing strings or integers from a separate function and have more than 10 items and only the first 10 are wanted.

Currently this just prints the last item in the list on 10 separate labels. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The all refer to the same `StringVar`, create a new one for each `Label` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a distinct `StringVar` for each `Label`. Currently, you just pass the same one to all the labels, so when you update it they all update together.

Here's an example. You didn't give a fully runnable program, so I had to fill in the gaps.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, StringVar

root = Tk()

list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10]

for v1, v2 in zip(list1, list2):

    item_values = '{} {}'.format(v1, v2)
    sv = StringVar()
    lbl = Label(root, width="100", height="2",textvariable=sv).pack()

    sv.set(item_values)

root.mainloop()
```