# Creating hyperlink Labels in tkinter using for loop, while binding each Label to different callbacks

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, label, bind

I got a dict like this:

```
dict = {"site1": link to site1,
        "site2": link to site2,
        "site3": link to site3,
        [...]
        }
```

and I don't know in advance how many sites will be inside the dict.

What I'm trying to achieve is binding different links to Labels created dynamically inside a for loop. I want to make a window with a list of names and when you click the name it will redirect you on the site.

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50341529/updating-labels-in-tkinter-with-for-loop) example below but without success.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, StringVar
import webbrowser

root = Tk()

list1 = ["site1-google","site2-facebook"]
list2 = ["google.com", "fb.com"]

for v1, v2 in zip(list1, list2):

    item_values = '{}'.format(v1)
    sv = StringVar()
    lbl = Label(root, width="100", height="2",textvariable=sv)
    lbl.pack()
    lbl.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: callback(v2))

    

    sv.set(item_values)
    
    def callback(url):
        webbrowser.open_new(url)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run the program it just bind the "last site" from list2 to all the freshly created Labels.

I read somewhere that lambda is late-binding, so it will bind every time the last value of the given list, but I don't know how to fix the problem!

How do I go on?

Comment: You probably don't need a `callback` function it can be done without it just do `lbl.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, url=v2: webbrowser.open_new(url))`

Comment: Well, that worked out! I really appreciate it man!
May I ask you how does this solution work? I'm still learning and couldn't find documentation about it, you came and resolved with a single line.!

Comment: When using `lambda` in a loop we need to pass arguments that are used in the lambda function otherwise only the last value of the for loop is considered *(You can further read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments))*